# Cannot find the code of a wordpress website

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm completely new to Wordpress and I trying to edit an existing website. Only thing is I can't find where the code is.

All the website's pages, listed in the **Pages** directory are empty (No blocks, just the title), so I figured the website was coded somewhere else.

Yet I cannot figure out where.

I could not find anything out there as I don't exactly know what I'm looking for.

Comment: I recommend starting here: [https://codex.wordpress.org](https://codex.wordpress.org)

Comment: Thanks, but I only need to do a one time change on this website, I would prefer to avoid reading all the WordPress documentation.

Comment: There are many places where things can be. It can be a plugin, it can be a theme, it can be a setting somewhere in admin, etc. There is no definite answer to your question sadly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content of Pages/Posts of a Wordpress website is stored in the databases in the posts & postmeta tables.

The core code of the Wordpress is stored on the folders:

- **/wp-admin**: contains the code the administration panel
- **/wp-includes**:contains the code  for the core of wordpress
- **/wp-content**: contains the code of plugins and the theme you have enabled.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. So on the **/wp-admin** I can't seem to find what I'm looking for, the **/wp-content** shows nothing and the **/wp-includes** returns a 403...

Comment: These are folders in the filesystem of your project. If you wish to change the code of your theme for example, you must edit the .php files of your wordpress installation.

Comment: And where are those located ? When trying to edit the installed theme, I can only manage to access the graphical editor, not the files.